# Html form (insert xquery) save in xml

Tags: html, xml, xquery

I have an html form, when I press the submit button I want to take the information and use the functions of Xquery so that with an (insert) xquery will be saved in the xml.

--html--

```
   <html>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.xq">
            <span ="label">Name:</span>
                <input type="text"/>
            <span ="label">Telephone:</span>
                <input type="text"/>
            <span ="label">Website:</span>
                <input type="text"/>
            <span ="label">Date:</span>
                <input type="text"/>
        <!-- Buttons submit and reset-->

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Delete"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

--exist-db XQUERY--

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace exist="http://exist.sourceforge.net/NS/exist";
declare namespace xmldb="http://exist-db.org/xquery/xmldb";
declare namespace request = "http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
update insert 
        <supplier id=" ">
            <name> </name>
            <telephone> </telephone>
            <website> </website>
            <date> </date>
        </supplier>

into doc("suppliers.xml")//supplier
```

--xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suppliers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="validate.xsd">

    <supplier id="1">
        <name>Microsoft</name>
        <telephone>943715587</telephone>
        <website>www.microsoft.com</website>
        <date>10/08/2016</date>
    </supplier>

</suppliers>
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Use REST interface and pass in those values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in the HTTP REST interface are accessed into variables in an XQuery using the request function set as in:

```
 let $name := request:get-parameter("name","")
 let $telephone := request:get-parameter("telephone","")
 let $website := request:get-parameter("website","")
 let $date := request:get-parameter("date","")
```

Then used as you would in the rest of the code as a XQuery variable:

```
 update insert 
    <supplier id=" ">
        <name>{$name}</name>
  ...
```

Now, that is a start. Your HTML needs name attributes on the input elements to pass them as parameters into the query. You need a return after the let's to return and the http request should be set to GET. And not knowing your system, the query and the documents would have to be open to all unless you are in some session-based environment and the HTML GET can find the XQuery based on some pathing in your controller or something.

This is essentially the same as http://path/to/myquery.xm?name=John%20Doe&telephone=123456789 ... and you want to grab the name and telephone.